# Save a gzipped html file on server by using PHP gzipp

Tags: php, html, gzip, save

I use this script to automatically save a PHP-file into a HTML file on my server:

```
<?php
$page=file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.com/index.php');
$fp=fopen('index.html','w+');
fputs($fp,$page);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

How can I get the server to also save a Gzipped version of index.php on the server?

The goal is to have the following files in the folder:

- turn-indexphp-into-indexhtml-and-indexgz.php
- index.php
- index.html
- index.gz

Comment: Remember that you can't get the actual source of the php-file because referencing _http://yourdomain.com/index.php_ yields the processed output of the code, e.g. HTML or what ever it might be.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you saying that it is impossible to use PHP to save a Gzipped version of index.php on my server?

Comment: you'll get the *output* of the file, not the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can only access the page by URL (ie. it is not a file on your own server), as pointed out by a few commenters - you will only be able to access the output of the PHP/ASP/Whatever file.

If it is not a Local File

```
<?php
$theUrl = 'http://www.server.com/filename.htm';
$theOutput = file_get_contents( $theUrl );
$outBase = preg_replace( '/[^\d\w]/' , '_' , $theUrl );
// Output standard HTML file (Filename may be clunky, but, up to you to fix that)
$outHTM = $outBase.'.htm';
file_put_contents( $outHTM , $theOutput );
// Output a GZipped version of same
$outGZ = $outBase.'.htm.gz';
$theOutput = gzencode( $theOutput , 9 );
file_put_contents( $outGZ , $theOutput );
?>
```

If it is a local file, then you can do the above, but also...

```
<?php
$theLocalFile = '/somefolder/anotherfolder/index.php';
$theLocalContent = file_get_contents( $theLocalFile );
$localBase = preg_replace( '/[^\d\w]/' , '_' , $theLocalContent );
// Save an uncompressed copy
$outLocal = $localBase.'.php';
file_put_contents( $outLocal , $theLocalContent );
// Save a GZipped copy
$outGZ = $localBase.'.php.gz';
$theOutput = gzencode( $theLocalContent , 9 );
file_put_contents( $outGZ , $theOutput );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Lucanos for pointing me in the right direction. gzencode() worked for me.